# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'

Tags: flutter, mobile-development

I was following tutorial and I get this error

> ' The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable'.

I tried to look on the documentation but I did know hoe to solve the error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'search.dart';
import 'user_info.dart';

import 'cart.dart';
import 'feed.dart';
import 'home.dart';

class BottomBarScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomBarScreenState createState() => _BottomBarScreenState();
}

class _BottomBarScreenState extends State<BottomBarScreen> {
  List<Map<String, Object>> _pages;
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pages = [
      {
        'page': home(),
     },
      {
        'page': feed(),
      },
      {
        'page': search(),
      },
  {
    'page': cart(),
  },
  {
    'page': user_info(),
  },
];
super.initState();
  }

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
    _selectedPageIndex = index;
   });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'],
```

Comment: Map types should be <String,Widget> you need to return Widget not Object to body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the start you have defined you `_pages` as `List<Map<String, Object>> _pages`.

Which means you only telling Dart that the value in the Map will only be Object.

You have specify it clearly like this,

```
List<Map<String, Widget>> _pages;
```

So that Dart understands that you are actually storing `Widget`s and not just `Object`s.

When you go and use it as `Scaffold's` body, the `body` expects a `Widget`. But from your earlier definition, all Dart can tell is that you are giving it an `Object`, which obviously won't work.

Answer (score 16):

Try to use  `body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,`

It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same case but I solved the problem in the map declaration:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _pages;
```

SDK environment : ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a Bottom Navigation Bar? if Yes, then check below code

```
  import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'Home.dart';
  import 'Fav.dart';
  import 'Search.dart';
  import 'Profile.dart';

  void main() {
           runApp(MyApp());
  }

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
               // This widget is the root of your application.
   @override
            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return MaterialApp(
                title: 'Flutter Demo',
                theme: ThemeData(

                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,

                visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
            ),
            home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Convex Bottom Bar'),
           );
        }
    }

        class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
            MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

             final String title;

             @override
             _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
            }

         class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

            int selectedPage = 0; // user selected page, initial 0 index page"Home()" 
            will be displayed to user
        
             final _pageOptions = [Home(),  Fav(),Search(), Profile()]; //4 different page where user can navigate.


         @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {

            return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                          title: Text(widget.title),
                         ),
                body: _pageOptions[selectedPage],
                bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(

                      items: [
                          TabItem(icon: Icons.home, title: 'Home'),
                          TabItem(icon: Icons.favorite, title: 'Favorites'),
                          TabItem(icon: Icons.search, title: 'Search'),
                          TabItem(icon: Icons.person, title: 'Profile'),
                        ],
                      initialActiveIndex: 0,//optional, default as 0
                      onTap: (int i ){
                                setState(() {
                                    selectedPage = I;
                                });
                              },
                     ),// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build 
                      methods.
                    );
                  }
               }
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed it form (List<Map<String, Object>> _pages;) to
late List<Map<String, Widget>> _pages; and everything is ok.

When I use it in Scaffold's body like (body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'],) <= I got error here.

the body expects a Widget. But from your earlier definition, all Dart can tell is that you are giving it an Object, which obviously won't work.